# Storybook SASSError expected "{"

Tags: reactjs, sass, storybook

I'm working on a design system with storybook and Sass.

I use css modules (with scss), but I have a bug when building Storybook, due to SASS :

```
SassError: expected "{".
node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[4]!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].use[1]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/Input/Input.scss undefined
  ╷
2 │       import API from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
  │                                                                                                     ^
  ╵
  src/components/Input/Input.scss 2:101  root stylesheet
```

I tried to totally delete my node_modules folder and to re-run `npm i` but npm returned me this :

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   36 more (@design-systems/utils, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/node_modules/react-inspector
npm WARN   react-inspector@"^5.1.0" from @storybook/addon-actions@6.5.15
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from react-inspector@5.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/node_modules/react-inspector
npm WARN     react-inspector@"^5.1.0" from @storybook/addon-actions@6.5.15
npm WARN     node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   36 more (@design-systems/utils, ...)

...
```

So I activated legacy peer deps with `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

And npm still returns me this message

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 2594 packages, and audited 2595 packages in 13s

364 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

28 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Note that I tried few weeks ago to totally reinstall node and I'm running Storybook with node 16.18.1 (I also tried with v19.2.0)

My node package.json is the following :

```json
{
  "name": "design-system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.2.1",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.14",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.46.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.46.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

(I added "@mdx-js/react": "^2.2.1" that was missing when building Storybook)

Comment: Stop futzing with your npm modules, there's no reason to think the dependency warnings are related to this problem.  The initial error message suggests you have a syntax error in `src/components/Input/Input.scss`, have you checked that?

Comment: It only contains this :
```@import "../../styles/mixins";

.input-container {
  @include flex-center;
  @include brdr-xs;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: $secondary100;
}```

Comment: @BaptisteAudugé did you ever fix the sass issue?